# How can I add volume control option and add a playlist in my audio player?

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to create a media player using wxpytohn. I want to add volume control option and also a playlist option in my player.

What should I do?

Here's my code:

```
import wx
import wx.media
class AudioPlayer(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"Audio Player",size=(400,200))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.media=wx.media.MediaCtrl(panel)
        b1=wx.Button(panel,-1,'Load',pos=(30,40),size=(60,30))
        b2=wx.Button(panel,-1,'Play',pos=(110,40),size=(60,30))
        b3=wx.Button(panel,-1,'Pause',pos=(180,40),size=(60,30))
        b4=wx.Button(panel,-1,'Stop',pos=(260,40),size=(60,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.load,b1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.play,b2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.pause,b3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.stop,b4)

    def load(self,event):
        stl=wx.OPEN
        filedia=wx.FileDialog(self,'open',style=stl)
        if filedia.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
            path=filedia.GetPath()
            self.media.Load(path)

    def play(self,event):
        self.media.Play()
    def pause(self,event):
        self.media.Pause()
    def stop(self,event):
        self.media.Forward()


app=wx.App()
frame=AudioPlayer(None,-1)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wx.Slider widget to create a volume control. You just need to set the media control's volume using its `SetVolume` method in the event hander for the slider. I wrote a little tutorial that demonstrates that concept here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/20/wxpython-creating-a-simple-mp3-player/

For a play list, I would recommend using a ListCtrl or one of its brethren. I prefer ObjectListView instead of a ListCtrl though:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/

If you decide to go that route, then make sure you download the latest version of it from here:

- http://objectlistview-python-edition.readthedocs.org/en/latest/